# How can i pass a parrameter from Asp to jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i have a Listview with dynamics rows that read them from database.
now i want when mouse is going on one of it's data perform special work on it.(like bellow code)

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
     $("*").mouseover(function () {//this line
         $("*").animate({             //this line
             width: "120px",
             height:"120px",

         }, 150);
});
```

my problem is that what i must write instead `*`,because their ids a changing dynamically and i can't user from `class` .
how can i do that?

Comment: if the id of rows generated are having a pattern or have a common class, you can try using live() api of jquery. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's not a direct answer to your question but in order to get the client id of any asp.net server control you could simple use:

`var controlId = '<%= txtBox1.ClientID %>' //where txtBox1 is the actual id specified in` markup

similarly, you can pass the client id of any control to javascript function, e.g.

```
function animate(id) {
$('$' + id).animate({             //this line
             width: "120px",
             height:"120px",

         }, 150);
}
```

//and to call this animate function from aspx markup

```
.... onfocus='animate('<%=ControlId.ClientID%>');
```

Answer (score 0):

set ClientIDMode of your control to `static` like `ClientIDMode="Static"` and give your control a ID that you remember, then you can easily get the value at the client side

say e.g.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="myTxtBox" ClientIDMode="static" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

in JS

```
var txt = $("#myTxTBox").text();
```

here is a good post http://www.shubho.net/2011/01/understanding-clientidmodepredictable.html